# Extend function does not call the base constructor

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have a component system that should extend from a base object called `component`.

New components can be registered via a function called `registerComponent()`. This function takes one parameter - the child class - and should inject the parent class `component` into it.

The following code almost handles this scenario, with the problem, that the `component` constructor is never called:

```js
// Base component.
function component() { 
  this.visible = false; 
  console.log('Construct component.'); 
}
component.prototype.isVisible = function() { 
  console.log('visibility:', this.visible); 
}

// Custom component that will be extended in a moment.
function button() { 
  this.caption = 'button'; 
  console.log('Construct button.'); 
}

// This is the function I need help with:
function registerComponent(obj) {
  function dynamicComponent() { 
    component.call(this); 
    obj.call(this);
  }

  dynamicComponent.prototype = Object.create(component.prototype);
  obj.prototype = Object.create(dynamicComponent.prototype);
  obj.prototype.constructor = obj;
}

// Now we register the button, which should add two things: 
// the property "this.visible"
// the method "this.isVisible()"
registerComponent(button);

// The test:
b = new button(); // Output is "Construct button."
                  // but not "Construct component." 
b.isVisible();    // Output is "visibility: undefined"
```

In the above code the method `component.prototype.isVisible()` is correctly injected into the button. However, the constructor is not called, and therefore the property `this.visible` is `undefined`, instead of `false`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `dynamicComponent` is never used anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
// This is the function I need help with:
function registerComponent(obj) {
  function dynamicComponent() { 
    component.call(this); 
    obj.call(this);
  }

  obj.prototype = dynamicComponent.prototype = Object.create(component.prototype);
  obj.prototype.constructor = dynamicComponent;

  return dynamicComponent;
}

const button = registerComponent(function() { 
  this.caption = 'button'; 
  console.log('Construct button.'); 
});

const b = new button();
```

You cannot alter an existing `button` function to make it implicitly call `component`.

Comment: That works perfectly and also makes total sense! Thanks for that clarification :)